# Replace template engine in FlightPHP with Plates

Tags: php, flightphp

the FlightPHP documentation outlines how to switch template engine to Smarty, but how would I instead switch to Plates? I have added Plates via composer and its autoloaded.

From Custom Views section: https://flightphp.com/learn#views

```
<?
Flight::register('view', 'Smarty', array(), function($smarty){
    $smarty->template_dir = './templates/';
    $smarty->compile_dir = './templates_c/';
    $smarty->config_dir = './config/';
    $smarty->cache_dir = './cache/';
});
?>
```

How can I add the Plates engine from here instead?
https://platesphp.com/engine/overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is exactly the same for Plates as it is for Smarty:

```php
<?php
require '../lib/vendor/autoload.php';

// Register Plates as the template engine
Flight::register('view', 'League\Plates\Engine', ['../lib/templates']);

// Override the default render method
Flight::map('render', function($template, $data){
    echo Flight::view()->render($template, $data);
});

Flight::route('/', function ()
{
    // Render the Plates template using Flight's render method
    Flight::render('hello', ['name' => 'World']);
});

Flight::start();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for taking time to not only answer but set it up and making sure it worked.